# Android: How Do i show the user's home screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, screen, screenshot

I'm trying to create an app that allows the user to open the android application... and it shows him his/her phone screen so i can add effects on it like cracked screen or something....?

Example if not clear...
Look at this url: and look at the first screenshot.

https://market.android.com/details?id=net.kreci.crackedscreen&hl=en

It captures the users home screen,

How do I start or code this in java

Thanks
Wally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I was wondering if it could be possible to capture the current display of another app.

But this is not possible due to the android rights management.

This app you mentioned just uses another effect: it has a transparent background and then applies some effects (in this case I think these are just transparent images) over this background.

There is a good tutorial on how this works:  http://www.41post.com/4213/programming/android-transparent-or-translucent-view-background